# Pygame display window opening and closing immediately

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I am having an issue trying to get the Pygame library to work on my Pycharm IDE. Even with this little bit of code Pygame seems to crash immediately after a window display is called. I am aware that this issue is common with syntax errors in code but it still crashes for me even with these 3 simple lines of code.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
```

Comment: Please add you code in the question and not add a hyperlink to a picture. Do you get an error message?

Comment: Sorry about that. I went ahead and made the change. But no, all I get is the window for about a second and then it disappears.

Answer (score 1):

You need an event loop, else the application will close immediately.

Look at the following code from http://pygametutorials.wikidot.com:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True
        self._display_surf = None
        self.size = self.weight, self.height = 640, 400

    def on_init(self):
        pygame.init()
        self._display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self._running = True

    def on_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self._running = False
    def on_loop(self):
        pass
    def on_render(self):
        pass
    def on_cleanup(self):
        pygame.quit()

    def on_execute(self):
        if self.on_init() == False:
            self._running = False

        while( self._running ):
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                self.on_event(event)
            self.on_loop()
            self.on_render()
        self.on_cleanup()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    theApp = App()
    theApp.on_execute()
```

The class method `on_execute` calls first the `on_init` method where pygame is intialized and the display mode is set, then the event loop is executed where pygame events are process and the current frame is rendered.

Only if an `pygame.QUIT` event is catched the event loop is exited and the `pygame.quit()` is called to cleanup the pygame environment. Then also the applications ends.

If this not helps share your crash message. Therefore try to execute your code from command line.

Comment: This seems to keep the window open perfectly, thanks! But one more question...will I always have to have this long chunk of code in my program in order for the window to start open? In all of the pygame tutorials I have seem most people just start by initializing and using draw methods without the need to use such loops. Is there an issue with my version?

Comment: By design any application wich is using the pygame library must somewhere process the events in a loop, else it will be either closed immediately or appearing 'not responsable'.

You can surely keep this event loop as small as possible, but you need one. Check also this tutorial: https://nerdparadise.com/programming/pygame

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It really helped a lot.